# place html in javascript strings?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, dom-manipulation

I need to place html in a javascript string.  Specifically, I would like to add an HTML link to a div tag with javascript.

html:

```html
<div id="mydivtag"></div>
```

javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('mydivtag').innerHTML = "<li><a href=\"someLink\">Some Link</a></li> ";
```

Am I formatting the html link I am adding through javascript correctly?

Comment: Does it work when you execute your code?

Comment: if its works u coded correctly

Comment: Yes you do, but you can use single quotes or nodes (document.createElement, appendChild)

Comment: in case you don't know about rendering html template, you should check http://handlebarsjs.com/. it'd make your process more robust and simpler to maintain later :)

Comment: I get the error message: Open quote is expected for attribute "href" associated with an  element type  "a".

Comment: I replaced \" with single quote, no error message, but the js doesn't work now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks fine and works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HnEu2/). You may want to consider mixing single quotes instead of escaping the double quotes, but that's just a preference.

```js
document.getElementById('mydivtag').innerHTML = "<li><a href='someLink'>Some Link</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have it in one line:

```
document.getElementById("mydivtag").appendChild(function(li, l, t) { li.appendChild(function(a, l, t) { a.href = l; a.innerHTML = t; return a; } (document.createElement("a"), l, t)); return li; } (document.createElement("li"), "mylink", "mytext"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs more jQuery:

```js
$('#mydivtag').html('<li><a href="someLink">Some Link</a></li>');
```

Comment: it needs less jQuery